# Why in my WordPress site PHP is not showing any error message

Tags: php, wordpress

In wp-config.php, I set as below:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

In php.ini, I set as below:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
html_errors = On
```

In spite of taking all the above steps, my site is not displaying error message. So it became difficult for me to debug/ troubleshoot my code errors. 
Can anybody give me a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your problem is.

If you've just changed setting in php.ini file, make sure that you restarted Apache.

To test your setting, you can trigger an error. E.g: add `trigger_error("Something goes wrong here");` in your index.php file.

Or, in case you want to use WP DEBUG, you can take a look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the current PHP session already apply the changes you made in php.ini file.
Or, you can apply all the php configuration above by using ini_set().

Just to reiterate, these should suffice:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

As a note, fatal error will not show you anything. You will need to check the log file to check this.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if there was some conflict between WP and PHP error settings.  Looking through php.net I found a note about issues when the PHP.ini `error_reporting` is set to a string and not an integer. Try `echo ini_get ("error reporting")` and see if you get an integer returned. If you don't see anything after "error reporting" then the ini isn't recognizing the error reporting setting because it is not an integer.

In http.conf use `php_admin_value error_reporting YOUR-INTEGER`

Source:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

Installing Xdebug will help you in this scenario.

https://xdebug.org/